# Possible to stream file from ADLS and decompress on the fly

Tags: python, azure, data-lake

```
with adl.open('folder123/azure.csv', blocksize=2**20) as x:
    for l in x:
        l = l.decode('utf-8')
        print(l)
```

This code will stream a file from ADLS in blocksizes.  Is it possible to do this with a bz2 file, decompress, and read line by line, by the same blocksize?